# Use svm-train.c and svm-predict.c from cpp program

Tags: c++, svm, libsvm

The truth is that I'm not an experienced C++ programmer, I'm a C# programmer and as all you know it's a lot different, on my machine learning experience I used just matlab, so please excuse me if I have some concept errors.

I'm trying to use libsvm on C++, I couldn't find a good example code showing how to use the library, I think the best reference is the [readme doc](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r94100/SVM_PRO/SLT_Proj/libsvm-2.81/README). They recommend to look at svm-train.c and svm-predict.c to figure how to use it, but there is a lot of low level stuffs that I want to avoid to do.

So, is there some way to just call svm-train and svm-predict from my cpp program, maybe instantiating it as an object or something? 
Or has someone a good example on how to train and test using libsvm over C++?
Or just give me some guidelines to goal this C++/libsvm challenge?

PS: I know that [this](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html) exists, but my professor ask me to use C++ due to performance issues (I was using matlab and it's horribly slow). I think there's a lot of C++ stuff I don't know and I'd really like to learn it, but I'm short on time and I'm hitting a wall with this.

Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 2):

The readme file you link to says

> **”** These functions and structures are declared in the header file `svm.h'.
>   You need to #include "svm.h" in your C/C++ source files and link your program with `svm.cpp'. You can see `svm-train.c' and `svm-predict.c'
>   for examples showing how to use them.

Me, I would try that.